# How to map a route on google maps using gps coordinates

Tags: gps, google-maps

If I were to collect a series of gps coordinates with a device, how could I view those points on google maps in a route?

Note that this is not a consumer device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the GPS co-ordinates to a KML file and import that into Google Maps (My Maps > Create a new map > Import).

Try using [this converter](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=googleearth) to start with.